# What all settings can be set with app.set()?

Tags: node.js, express, application-settings

The [official documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set) shows a very trivial setting being set

```
app.get('title');
// => undefined

app.set('title', 'My Site');
app.get('title');
// => "My Site"
```

But [I've seen things like](https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO/blob/master/config/index.js)

```
log('Save configuration values in app %j', config);
app.set('config', config);

log('Setting port as %d', config.app.port);
app.set('port', config.app.port);

log('Setting view engine as %s', 'jade');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

being set with that method. Which are definitely not as trivial.

What exactly is happening here that isn't detailed in the official doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Going straight to the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L289), there doesn't seem to be anything special about `app.set` at all.  It just updates an internal `settings` property that is an object containing seemingly anything.  For Balloons.IO:

- [port](https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO/blob/master/balloons.js#L45) to set the server port
- [config](https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO/blob/master/strategy.js#L25) (also used in other places, but it's retrieved the same way)

However, express does have some special settings that it uses internally [in the express documentation here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings).

Other libraries that use express may also have settings that they use internally.